# Putting your Image on a Dark background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have struggled with this for years
I want to know how to put an image for example a picture of my self on a black/dark background Such as the one in the attachment

Please any ideas, tutorials  or videos i can watch to achieve this level of excellence [image]

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 4):

For best results the **photo is taken** with a black background.

Generally it's best to have this done by a *professional* photographer so they can set appropriate lighting as well.

*This is how your sample image was created*.

If you are seeking to alter the existing background of an existing photograph, there are many examples on this site about how to remove a background. 
[Click here to see local search results based on "background removal".](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=replace%20background) You can then choose the question/answer which best fits your needs, such as Photoshop vs Gimp.

Comment: Ok sounds like the  only way out is to actually take that photo with professional photographers.  I was thinking one could use a software like photoshop, pixlr etc to achieve this  -  Thanks for your response - Pls if any other person has got some other ideas - pls share

Comment: Well, you can use software to achieve some results @Jumo that's why I suggested [searching this site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=replace+background). There are *many* questions related to that. You can often get a decent result, your sample is a professional photograph though. which is *always* the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a good quality high resolution photo which is taken in usual quite light conditions, no black background and studio lights. Let's also assume that you can remove the background in high resolution.

The biggest problem now is the contradiction between the black background and the light in the photo. There probably are some too bright edges due the ambient light, even some color can be sticked to the edges due the bright colors in the original background.

The solution: Add a layer (=Fade mask) above the photo layer which makes the edges darker. Let it have blending mode multiply and fill it at first with white (=no effect). Then carefully with soft, low opacity brush insert slowly black until just the problematic edges are vanished.

As well you can paint a white shape onto black. In the following example (presents nobody and nothing related in the real world) the latter is applied. The white shape was blurred and a little more black was sprayed at the edge. This resulted nice gradual darkening.

[image]

Comment: You can also darken the photo smoothing the highlights.

Comment: Like in the example, some text over the photo gives more depth.